# How to solve RuntimeErrror and TypeError on Windows in Python Multithreading Application?

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, github

I recently found the sentiment analysis application [streamcrab](https://github.com/cyhex/streamcrab/tree/master/smm) on GitHub.

While it is perfectly running on Mac it does not on Windows. This is the result of the fact that the author of the project does not have experience on Windows and did not keep in mind the differences according to multithreading when he developed the application.

On Windows the application throws two exceptions when running the start-classifier.py script:

```
RuntimeError:
    Attempt to start a new process before the current process
    has finished its bootstrapping phase.

    This probably means that you are on Windows and you have
    forgotten to use the proper idiom in the main module:

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            freeze_support()
            ...

    The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
    is not going to be frozen to produce a Windows executable.


TypeError: can't pickle thread.lock objects
```

The classifier consists of four main parts:

- Main - Initialization
- Pool - manages workers
- Worker - manages classifier
- Classification - responsible for the classification of the tweets

I have already tried to add an if-main-condition to the start-classifier.py script, however that lead to the situation that no worker was started at all.

I cannot post the code of the classifier here since it is distributed over many files and I am also not sure which parts of the code cause the errors.

I have also opened an [issue](https://github.com/cyhex/streamcrab/issues/25) for the problem on GitHub.